How can I detect and rectify this AttributeError in my Android app
I am trying to develop an Android application using kivy and kivymd while connecting to a SQLite database and after running the code, I got the below error
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'md_menu'
 
 
   File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?

Process finished with exit code 1

I have checked all my indentations and also asked an AI, and I was told the ids of one of my custom methods may be not be available in the kivymd library.
This is the link to my code.
This is my first time building an Android application.

Please follow this guideline if you expect to get help. In short, (a) minimal code, (b) what you expected to happen, and (c) what really happened. It is good that you have part (c) here, but still missing other parts. Do not post a link to your code, but paste your code here.

I don't think you can use a MDDropdownMenu in kv. It is not specifically stated in the documentation, but if you look at the documentation you will see that none of the examples use it in kv. The typical use is to declare a Button in the kv which (when pressed) creates and opens the MDDropdownMenu.
